# Batch program to build a module of my project

Tags: java, windows, maven, batch-file, build

I have written a simple batch program to build a module of my project which builds using Maven.

My batch is as follows

```
@echo off

set jarBuildPath=D:\ANGSHU\project-

:jar
  set /p module=Enter Which Module You Want To Build?[e.g. test]

  pushd %jarBuildPath%%module%
  IF %ERRORLEVEL% ==1  (
echo.
echo Module you entered [%module%] does not exist
goto jar
  )
  echo Build process started...
  build -Dmaven.test.skip clean install > %module%-build-output-log.txt
  echo Build process is over...
  start "" "%jarBuildPath%%module%\%module%-build-output-log.txt"
GOTO End1

:End1
```

In the above code the lines after the build command is not executing.
I have created the batch and created a shortcut for the batch and i have changed the properties of the shortcut to change the target as D:\ANGSHU\Build\Build.bat &PAUSE
which makes the batch wait after it finishes but still the next two lines

```
echo Build process is over...
start "" "%jarBuildPath%%module%\%module%-build-output-log.txt"
```

is not executing.Can anyone help me with my problem??

Comment: Not sure about Maven or your environment, but, if as usual, build is a batch file, the way you are calling it changes the execution to the build batch and does not return. Instead, use `call build .....` so when the build process ends your batch file continue.

Comment: yes build is a batch file
but 
call build -Dmaven.test.skip clean install is not working

Comment: And what you get? Any error, log, message, ...?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the file is not being written where you thought it was.  This does not do what you might have expected:

```
pushd %jarBuildPath%%module%
```

Perhaps you wanted:

```
pushd .
cd %jarBuildPath%%module%

REM build etc...

popd
```

Of course, you could be more specific instead:

```
build -Dmaven.test.skip clean install > "%jarBuildPath%%module%\%module%-build-output-log.txt"
```